# Make teaching a synonym of education

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

I propose making [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) a synonym of [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education), because they are fairly closely related and questions on education should go to Mathematics Educators anyway.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/496/the-difference-between-teaching-and-education?rq=1

Comment: And this one, too: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/19125#19125

Comment: When I saw the title of this post I thought it was going to be a profound mission statement.

Comment: Since this has positive support in like 3 different places, I just tried to propose teaching as a synonym of education. But I got a weird error: "Failed to propose synonym: Reverse synonym teaching already proposed on the tag pedagogy". Anyone know what this means?

Comment: Related to this error? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179579/not-able-to-propose-a-tag-synonym-which-was-previously-proposed-as-a-synonym-of

Comment: I think a mod needs to disconnect the synonyms and then reconnect.

Comment: @6005 If A is a synonym of B, then B can't be a synonym of anything. The only relation supported is having one master tag and a bunch of its synonyms. So, since pedagogy is a synonym of teaching, one can't make teaching a synonym of any other tag. Without mods getting involved, that is.

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks. I've requested it be implemented in the math mods' office.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I did it. [pedagogy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) and [teaching](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) are now synonyms of [education](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education). I also modified the tag wiki to suggest mathed.se for users who desire a more granular selection of subtopics.